# iOS Image View turn off selection highlighting

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, overlay, highlight

Bit of a strange question, so i've attached a screen recording to help...

Video : https://www.dropbox.com/s/3aaefixsk8eejln/Error.mov (See past the watermark!)

My issue is that in my application when the user is at the "Preview" view and is reviewing their images, each time the image is selected, the image receives a touched overlay, which could be confusing for a user as nothing happens when touched.

I would like to disable this if possible..

Below is the example code to how the images are being displayed..

```
 - (void)setReviewImages
{
    continueButtonDisabled = YES;
    downloadedImageCount = 0;

    NSArray *reviewViews = scrollView.subviews;
    for (IMReviewView *reviewView in reviewViews) {
        [reviewView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSUInteger photoCount = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoCount];
    if ( nPageNum == 0 ){
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < photoCount; i++) {

            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x  = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
            frame.origin.y  = 65;
            frame.size      = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 327.0f);

            IMReviewView *subview = [[IMReviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            subview.delegate = self;
            subview.photo = [[IMLocalUser localUser] cachedPhotoAtIndex:i];
            [scrollView addSubview:subview];

            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * i, scrollView.frame.size.height);

            UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 30)];
            [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];


            headingLabel.text = @"Time To Preview!";
            headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            headingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

            headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            headingLabel.tag = 10;
            headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            headingLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:26.0f];
            headingLabel.hidden = NO;
            headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
            headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
            headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to be collection view for this thing...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like `IMReviewView` has a `UIButton` subview. If so, try to set its [`adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted) property to `NO`.